# WCF 4 service responds to localhost address but not machine name

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, wcf-4

I am building a very simple WCF 4 service to test SharePoint External content list.

When I run the service, this works fine:

```
http://localhost:49669/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

But this does not:

```
http://machinename:49669/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

In the old 3.5 wcf services I would just update the config, but here the config files are empty.

What is the minimum that I need to put in the config file to get it to work, or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the integrated Visual Studio web server (Cassini), you cannot acess it from a different machine as only local access is allowed

You'll need to deploy your service or use IIS express to consume your service from a different machine